# NE has derailed

Tags: discussion

- The majority of people participated in the definition and commitment (2013) have been long gone from NE for good reasons.
- Most questions that did not get closed are trivial vendor specific questions, questions that can be answered by LMGTFY
- Quite a few questions [[example](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/335/revisions)] are edited (by the same people)
  in a very unprofessional (or grossly disrespectful) manner
- The activity at NE is mostly from 1) home networking questions 2) the
  few nazis satisfying their ego 3) people too lazy to go to the right
  place to ask the questions and expecting NE to be a catch-all (me
  included).

I didn't entirely give up on NE as my name was somehow still on NE area51 commitment page and I invited people here before open beta. Now I am actually ashamed to wear the NE shirt because of what NE has turned into.

In short, don't waste your time on NE.

I would not be surprised if this post gets closed/hijacked by editing.

Comment: Two down votes, 0 comments or input as to why. I get the OP is a little heated, but the points brought up are worth addressing.

Comment: My answer is, "I disagree". If OP here wanted to ask a question, perhaps something like, "how do we change the stack's focus..." then that might lead to discussion and suggestions. (might.) Meanwhile this is simply OP's statement of opinion.

Comment: ...also, I'd be surprised if it was closed. I don't recall ever seeing a *meta* post closed or deleted (other than by an OP.)

Comment: There is no requirement to comment on a down vote, especially on meta (feel free to search SE/SO meta for multiple questions on this). On meta, a down vote is simply a "I don't agree with this question/answer."

Comment: It would seem to me that you are really griping that NE has not derailed in the same way that other SE sites have. It looks to me like NE has been much more faithful to the original proposition than many of the other SE sites. It think that part of this the smaller size of NE than sites like SO, where I get chastised by the moderators for flagging a clearly off-topic post which exactly matches what is defined as off-topic for that site. This has happened to me on several other sites.

Answer (score 8):

Let me preface my answer by stating outright that the entire "question" comes across quite a bit like a "troll" posting. Lots of ambiguous criticisms with very little "meat" in the post.

> The majority of people participated in the definition and commitment (2013) have been long gone from NE for good reasons.

This is rather ambiguous and unhelpful. What would you propose those reasons are? Life/family changes? Job changes? A change in interests? If so, then I could agree those are probably good reasons to no longer participate in an online community.

People come and go to many online communities for many reasons, and most of them would consider their own reasons to be good reasons.

> Most questions that did not get closed are trivial vendor specific questions, questions that can be answered by LMGTFY

First, this is pure speculation on your part. I would be interested in actual statistics to back this up.

Second, most online communities are filled with the same types of questions. People go where they feel comfortable and feel they will get a good answer to their question. Is that a bad thing for people to feel like they may get good answers here?

Is it bad that they feel the quality of the answers will be higher here than from "random" results from a Google search?

> Quite a few questions [example] are edited (by the same people) in a very unprofessional (or grossly disrespectful) manner

Perhaps a quick viewing of the deleted comments can shed some light on this edit:[image]

Indeed it does. The OP asked an off topic question on NE, it got closed, OP argued about it being on topic, it was suggested that discussion/question should be asked on meta and the OP copied the same question from NE to meta. A moderator (at the time) edited the question to fit with what was suggested.

I won't argue whether the edit could have been better, but the edit is clearly more in line with what the OP should have asked on meta rather than simply repeat his off topic question on meta.

Also, just for reference, let's take a look at the comments from the OP's closed question to see how this was handled by this "unprofessional (or grossly disrespectful)" individual:[image]

Hmmm. Seems like this individual tried to be helpful by providing at least a partial answer to an off topic question and a pointer to meta (an unknown resource to the OP).

> The activity at NE is mostly from 1) home networking questions 2) the few nazis satisfying their ego 3) people too lazy to go to the right place to ask the questions and expecting NE to be a catch-all (me included).

Again, this seems to be pure speculation on your part and I would prefer actual statistics.

Sure, we get lots of home networking questions. We have had this discussion before and we always knew it was going to happen. People see the "network" part of the site and most don't take the time to read the FAQs before posting. Again this is not uncommon on most online communities.

The "nazis" comment is entirely uncalled for and in itself is more unprofessional and disrespectful than the actions of the individual you accused above. Please keep in mind that this term is grossly offensive to many people globally.

Finally, where is the "right place" to ask questions online?  Could you provide me a directory that would indicate where the "right place" is for my next question so that I am not perceived as "too lazy" to go there?

> I didn't entirely give up on NE as my name was somehow still on NE area51 commitment page and I invited people here before open beta. Now I am actually ashamed to wear the NE shirt because of what NE has turned into.
>
> In short, don't waste your time on NE.

You are certainly entitled to your opinion. As someone else who was part of this since before closed beta, I guess I just don't understand what you think is so drastically different than what was proposed on Area51.

However, since you have been here so long, then if there really is a problem, the fault lies with you as much as anyone else. The community has helped to define this site and if you chose to not participate in shaping it, we can't help that.

> I would not be surprised if this post gets closed/hijacked by editing.

Yet another accusation without providing any real basis. If it is deleted, I would suspect that is is more inline with how little merit the post actually contains that brings this full circle to my "troll" post comment I opened with.

Comment: I have wondered if it would be possible, not just on NE, but other (all?) SE sites as well, to redirect someone who has not previously asked a question on the site to the on-topic page with a check box for the person to agree that the person has read which topics are on/off-topic prior to being allowed to ask a first question.

Comment: @RonMaupin, the problem is you don't have to have an account to post a question. So this may get repeated and annoy people who don't have accounts.

Comment: I can see that, but it may prod someone to actually get an account. It's just a suggestion for people above my pay grade to mull over. :)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to write this beautiful answer.

Comment: Good job on completely hijacking the proposal (as to what is OT) and suppressing any opinion you don't agree with (closing, editing).  My UID is 34 and yours is 33, and nobody with < 33 is still active as of 2016. I am truly impressed by the amount of effort you guys put in to kill this site. What's uncalled for? How many of us have been disrespected by the most active "moderators" (even without being an actual moderator). Even if you consider something OT, it doesn't make it justified to edit the OP to reflect your understandings and humiliate the OP.

Comment: You want answers without opinions at all, go write a Cisco press certification book, jk...Even RFCs are opinion based to a certain degree. I know I am fighting a losing battle here as NE has long past the point of no return. I will vote with my feet just like others. This post is really meant to remind newcomers from Google: Don't waste your time here. There is no answer but disrespect and hostility.

Comment: Again you reply with baseless accusations and nothing constructive. You say we have "hijacked" the proposal of what is OT, could you show me where? As to the inactive users, shall we go to the other SE sites and see how many <33 user IDs are still active? Fact is the majority of people often don't stay at online communities for long. As a moderator, how many examples can you provide where I have disrespected people? And the referenced edit was an attempt to help a user new to meta what should have been asked (and was specifically asked by the OP in the comments). No humiliation there.